# Java: Checking the correctness of brackets using stacks

Tags: java, string, char, stack

In this program, I am trying to check whether the brackets in an inputted string are balanced. For example, `(9*[3+4])` is correct and `{10/[4+9)` isn't. However ,whenever I try to run my program and enter the input.

A lot of problems come up. When I input the string `([{}])`, then it says the brackets aren't balanced and when i input `([])` then it gives me an empty stack exception. I am fairly new to the idea of stacks, so i am having a lot of trouble with this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Stack;

public class BracketCheck {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Stack stk = new Stack();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean balance = true;

        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String str = s.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if(str.charAt(i) == '(' || str.charAt(i) == '[' 
            || str.charAt(i) == '{') { //if the char is an opening bracket then add to stack
                stk.push(str.charAt(i));
            }
            else if(str.charAt(i) == ')' || str.charAt(i) == ']' ||
            str.charAt(i) == '}') { //if char is a closing bracket
                if(!stk.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(stk.peek()); // to check if the bracket was added
                    if((stk.pop().equals('(') && str.charAt(i) != ')') ||
                    (stk.pop().equals('[') && str.charAt(i) != ']') ||
                    (stk.pop().equals('{') && str.charAt(i) != '}')) {
                        // this is where i believe the empty stack exception occurs
                        balance = false;
                        System.out.println("Brackets don't match");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else { // flase because there is no opeing bracket to match with the closing bracket
                    balance = false;
                    System.out.println("There is no opening bracket");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (balance == true) {
            System.out.println("The equation is balanced");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The equation is not balanced");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: `if ("([{".indexOf(str.charAt(i)) >= 0)` is a much easier way to check if you're at an opening bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you keep on calling `stk.pop()` when you're checking if the bracket matches.

```
if((stk.pop().equals('(') && str.charAt(i) != ')') ||
    (stk.pop().equals('[') && str.charAt(i) != ']') ||
    (stk.pop().equals('{') && str.charAt(i) != '}')) {
```

Pop once, store in a variable, use that variable instead of `stk.pop()` in the condition.

```
Character pop = stk.pop();
if((pop.equals('(') && str.charAt(i) != ')') ||
    (pop.equals('[') && str.charAt(i) != ']') ||
    (pop.equals('{') && str.charAt(i) != '}')) {
```

You can also use primitive `char` as the type of `pop`, and just use plain `==`, e.g. `char pop = stk.pop(); if (pop == '(' || ...`.

---

As I point out in a comment above, you can check if a character is in a list of characters using a string:

```
if ("([{".indexOf(str.charAt(i)) >= 0) { ... }
```

You can use this in the matching check too:

```
int idx = ")]}".indexOf(str.charAt(i));
if (idx >= 0 && "([{".charAt(idx) != pop) {
  // They don't match!
}
```

Comment: I believe there is one further problem with the OP code: Consider the test case "("; 'balanced will remain true; the final check for correctness should also include stk.isEmpty().

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Ian sure, that too. Didn't get that far in the code tbh.

Answer (score 0):

The issues with pop and empty stack are already addressed. You may also consider separating your bracket characters from the checking code, and putting that code in a separate method:

```
import java.util.*;

    public class BracketCheck
    {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
       {
          Map<Character, Character> brackets = new Hashtable<>();
          brackets.put(']', '[');
          brackets.put('}', '{');
          brackets.put(')', '(');


          Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("Enter a string");

          System.out.format("balanced: %b%n", isBalanced(s.nextLine(), brackets));
       }

       public static boolean isBalanced(String str, Map<Character, Character> brk)
       {
          Stack<Character> stk = new Stack<>();

          for (char c : str.toCharArray())
          {
             if (brk.containsValue(c))
             {
                stk.push(c);
             }
             else
             {
                if (brk.containsKey(c))
                {
                   if (stk.isEmpty() || !brk.get(c).equals(stk.pop()))
                   {
                      return false;
                   }
                }
             }
          }

          return stk.isEmpty();
       }
    }
```